# AngularJS html5mode URL not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, html5mode

I have a simple AngularJS application with no code related to nodeJS in it. I'm facing problem in removing # from url. I've used ui-routes for routing.

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui-router']).
        config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
               $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $stateProvider.
                        state('home', {
                            url: '/',
                            templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
                        })
                        .state('where-am-i', {
                            url: '/where-am-i',
                            templateUrl: 'views/where_am_i.html',
                            controller: 'mainCtrl'
                        })
                        .state('audience', {
                            url: '/audience',
                            templateUrl: 'views/audience.html',
                            controller: 'mainCtrl'
                        });

            }]);
```

Also added base tag to the head section of my index.html.

```
<base href='/' />
```

Also tried require no base but still not able to get it working.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
```

Adding base tag shows 404 for all the assets I've included in index.html file.

Need a quick and simple solution for this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are getting `404` errors, then the browser would seem to be that the URLs doesn't exist on the server. Use the Network tab to figure out exactly what URLs are being requested, then fix the server. (Note that your question includes no information about what server you are using or how it is configured).

Comment: How is your index.html? If you are getting 404 on your assets, there is something wrong in the way you are inclunding them...

Comment: Currently, my application is in development stage so I'm running it on localhost like [http://localhost/projectname].

Also with `<base href="/" />` I'm including all the assets directly starting from assets folder as my assets folder is placed in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

add a line after `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` as below:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

hope it works.